# React + Codeigniter Response for preflight is invalid

Tags: php, reactjs, codeigniter

I have a website that was built using codeigniter MVC but following modern trends I'm trying to create a frontend based on react. I still want to use original codeigniter framework and controllers but instead or rendering views I want it to return plain JSON. Currently I'm stuck on being unable to send requests from react application that runs in debug mode on localhost:3000 to my codeigniter api that is running on apache http://mywebsite:80

this is how I'm initiating request:

```
fetch("http://mywebsite/Api" + route + '/', {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        redirect: 'follow',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType : 'json'
      })
```

This is the error I'm getting in a console:

> Failed to load http://mywebsite/ApiAuth/login/: Response for preflight
>   is invalid (redirect)

My php page sends the following back:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS, POST, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
```

Console outputs:

```
Request URL: http://mywebsite/ApiAuth/login/
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Comment: I hope you have auth checking via token or something. You should disable auth checking for `OPTIONS` request and return the headers only.

Comment: This is an issue on Backend Server. You need to configure your nginx/apache redirect OPTIONS -> return 200.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix the issue by setting Apache response headers and redirect method like this:

```
#Redirect for CORS Preflight request              
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]

#Set headers to access CORS Requests / allowing localhost only
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header always add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```